# How can I turn a tree into a string of bracket representation in C?

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node_st {
    int data;
    struct node_st* left;
    struct node_st* right;
};

void preorder(struct node_st *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct node_st *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
    }
}

struct node_st* createNode(value) {
    struct node_st* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node_st));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct node_st* insertLeft(struct node_st* root, int value){
    root->left = createNode(value);
    return root->left;
}

struct node_st* insertRight(struct node_st* root, int value){
    root->right = createNode(value);
    return root->right;
}


int main() {
    struct node_st* root = createNode(2);
    insertLeft(root, 6);
    insertRight(root, 9);
    insertLeft(root->left, 2);
    insertLeft(root->right, 1);

    printf("\nPreorder\n");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\nPostorder\n");
    postorder(root);
}
```

I need to make a function to store a tree into a string with bracket representation like (A(B)(C)) and to read it to make a tree, but I'm having trouble finding info online on how to do this in C, would appreciate any help.

The next step after this is to store it and read it from a file, but I can handle that with the documentation.

Comment: What tree does the `(A(B)(C))` string represent?  Is `A` the parent node and `(B)` and `(C)` are the child nodes, or are you using some other form.  One symmetric way to represent a tree with A at the top, B as the left child and C as the right child is `((B)A(C))`, for example.  And if `B` has a right child `D`, it might be `((()B(D))A(C))`.  How do you want to represent empty child nodes in a non-leaf node (that is, a node where either the left or the right child pointer is null, but not both)?

Comment: Yes A is the parent node and (B) and (C) are the child nodes.
For example if I wanted to make it bigger, (A(B(C)(D))(E))
So A is the parent node of B and E and B is the parent node of C and D

Comment: When a child node is null, it just isn't represented, for example (A(B)), A has only one non-null child.

Comment: As long as you realise that means some trees cannot be accurately reconstructed from the printed output, that is a legitimate design decision, albeit not one I would make of my own volition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that prints the tree in bracketed representation.  The format you request is ambiguous — if a node has only one child, you cannot tell whether that child is the left child or the right child.  That ambiguous format is produced by the functions with `_v1_` in the name: `print_v1_tree()`, `print_v1_preorder()`, `print_v1_postorder()`, `print_v1_inorder()`.

There is an alternative format where an empty subtree is represented by `()` unless the node is a leaf node (both child nodes are null).

There's also a `free_tree()` function to release the memory for a tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_st
{
    int data;
    struct node_st *left;
    struct node_st *right;
} Node;

typedef void (*Print)(const Node *node);

extern struct node_st *createNode(int value);
extern struct node_st *insertLeft(struct node_st *root, int value);
extern struct node_st *insertRight(struct node_st *root, int value);
extern void postorder(struct node_st *root);
extern void preorder(struct node_st *root);
extern void inorder(struct node_st *root);

extern void print_v1_postorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v1_inorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v1_preorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v1_tree(const char *tag, const Node *node, Print print);

extern void print_v2_postorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v2_inorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v2_preorder(const Node *node);
extern void print_v2_tree(const char *tag, const Node *node, Print print);

extern void free_tree(Node *node);

void preorder(struct node_st *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct node_st *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
    }
}

void inorder(struct node_st *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

struct node_st *createNode(int value)
{
    struct node_st *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node_st));
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for a node\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct node_st *insertLeft(struct node_st *root, int value)
{
    root->left = createNode(value);
    return root->left;
}

struct node_st *insertRight(struct node_st *root, int value)
{
    root->right = createNode(value);
    return root->right;
}

void print_v1_preorder(const Node *node)
{
    printf("%d", node->data);
    if (node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_preorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    if (node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_preorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
}

void print_v1_inorder(const Node *node)
{
    if (node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_inorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    printf("%d", node->data);
    if (node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_inorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
}

void print_v1_postorder(const Node *node)
{
    if (node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_postorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    if (node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v1_postorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
    printf("%d", node->data);
}

void print_v1_tree(const char *tag, const Node *node, Print print)
{
    printf("%s: (", tag);
    if (node != NULL)
        (*print)(node);
    putchar(')');
    putchar('\n');
}

void print_v2_preorder(const Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d", node->data);
    if (node->left != NULL || node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_preorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    if (node->right != NULL || node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_preorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
}

void print_v2_inorder(const Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (node->left != NULL || node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_inorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    printf("%d", node->data);
    if (node->right != NULL || node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_inorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
}

void print_v2_postorder(const Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (node->left != NULL || node->right != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_postorder(node->left);
        putchar(')');
    }
    if (node->right != NULL || node->left != NULL)
    {
        putchar('(');
        print_v2_postorder(node->right);
        putchar(')');
    }
    printf("%d", node->data);
}

void print_v2_tree(const char *tag, const Node *node, Print print)
{
    printf("%s: (", tag);
    if (node != NULL)
        (*print)(node);
    putchar(')');
    putchar('\n');
}

/* Must be post-order release, but could do right before left */
void free_tree(Node *node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        free(node->left);
        free(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node_st *root = createNode(3);

    insertLeft(root, 6);
    insertRight(root, 9);
    insertLeft(root->left, 2);
    insertLeft(root->right, 1);

    printf("\nPreorder\n");
    preorder(root);
    printf("\nPostorder\n");
    postorder(root);
    printf("\nInorder\n");
    inorder(root);

    printf("\nAmbiguous:\n");
    print_v1_tree("Preorder",  root, print_v1_preorder);
    print_v1_tree("Inorder",   root, print_v1_inorder);
    print_v1_tree("Postorder", root, print_v1_postorder);
    print_v1_tree("Empty",     NULL, print_v1_inorder);

    printf("\nUnambiguous:\n");
    print_v2_tree("Preorder",  root, print_v2_preorder);
    print_v2_tree("Inorder",   root, print_v2_inorder);
    print_v2_tree("Postorder", root, print_v2_postorder);
    print_v2_tree("Empty",     NULL, print_v2_inorder);

    insertRight(root->right, 13);
    insertRight(root->left, 3);
    insertRight(root->left->right, 4);
    insertRight(root->left->right->right, 5);

    printf("\nExtended tree - unambiguous:\n");
    print_v2_tree("Preorder",  root, print_v2_preorder);
    print_v2_tree("Inorder",   root, print_v2_inorder);
    print_v2_tree("Postorder", root, print_v2_postorder);
    print_v2_tree("Empty",     NULL, print_v2_inorder);

    free_tree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Preorder
3
6
2
9
1

Postorder
2
6
1
9
3

Inorder
2
6
3
1
9

Ambiguous:
Preorder: (3(6(2))(9(1)))
Inorder: (((2)6)3((1)9))
Postorder: (((2)6)((1)9)3)
Empty: ()

Unambiguous:
Preorder: (3(6(2)())(9(1)()))
Inorder: (((2)6())3((1)9()))
Postorder: (((2)()6)((1)()9)3)
Empty: ()

Extended tree - unambiguous:
Preorder: (3(6(2)(3()(4()(5))))(9(1)(13)))
Inorder: (((2)6(()3(()4(5))))3((1)9(13)))
Postorder: (((2)(()(()(5)4)3)6)((1)(13)9)3)
Empty: ()
```

Converting this to store the data in a string is not too difficult.  Parsing it is fiddlier — regardless of which format you use.  Preorder may be the easiest to handle.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for storing a tree in a string, using sprintf (return number of chars stored), given:

1. A node to begin storing (root on first call)
2. A pre alocated string, you can modify the code to realloc
3. The position on the string you are printing (i)
4. The max size of the string

````
    int string_parenthesis_by_node(node_t *nd, char *str, int i, int max){
    if (!nd) return 0;

    // checks the size limit
    int added = (ceil(log10(nd->key > 0 ? nd->key : 1)) + 2);
    if (i + added >= max){
        fprintf(stderr, "TOO LARGE INPUT TO BUFFER, tried to add %d on top of %d, maxing %d", added, i, max);
        return 0;
    }

    // res is the current position you are storing
    // it is incremented after every sprint
    int res = i;
    res += sprintf(str+res, "(%d", nd->key);
    res += string_parenthesis_by_node(nd->left, str, res, max);
    res += string_parenthesis_by_node(nd->right, str, res, max);
    res += sprintf(str+res, ")");

    return res-i;
}```
````